# Git rebase is missing non-conflict files when applying a patch fails

Tags: git, github, rebase, git-rebase, git-merge-conflict

Ran into a peculiar problem that was reproducible on one MacBook Pro (we'' call this the bad one), one Windows using msysgit, but not on another MacBook Pro (we'll call this the good one).

Rebased a feature branch off of master that was only 1 commit behind master. The feature branch had 1 new commit, so your standard rebase work flow.

On the good MacBook, you do your standard `git pull --rebase origin master` or `git rebase -i origin/master`. Everything goes smoothly to the conflict step. `git status` will show the files that do not have conflicts in green, and the ones that do and that you must resolve in red. You resolve the conflicts and do a `git rebase --continue`, check the history/logs again and everything is clean.

On the bad MacBook and the windows machine, we begin the rebase but when we get to the conflict resolution step, we only see the files that require conflict resolution and the **files that do not need resolution are not there**. If we resolve the conflict resolution, the new rebased feature branch loses all the files that did not have conflicts.

Upon investigation we noticed that a patch failed to be applied. The message was:

`the copy of the patch that failed is found in .git/rebase-apply/patch`

So we check the patch file and it indeed had a full list of changes.

We tried to clear the resolution history with `git rerere forget .` thinking that maybe the dev did some conflict resolution before but the same thing happened.

On the good MacBook, this message didn't occur and everything was fine.

We are looking into `git am` but haven't found any leads. There are no other hints in the error messages as well.